# java synchronized and shared tables

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have singleton object (class) that has a table (hashmap). All the other objects (clients) read the list of other clients that are stored inside the table. All methods using the table have been surrounded with synchronized keyword. I have debugged a situation where the table has different values for different clients. Clients may or may not be running on the same thread thats why i added the synchronized keyword.

here is the methods using the hashmap:

```
public synchronized Client addToConnectedClients(long key, Client client)
{
    return allConnectedClients.put(key, client);
}   

public synchronized Client getFromConnectedClients(long key)
{
    return allConnectedClients.get(key);
}

public synchronized Client removeFromConnectedClients(long key)
{
    return allConnectedClients.remove(key);
}
```

here is how i access the table from inside a client object:

```
Client temp=AppInterface.getInstance().getAppNetworkLogic().getFromConnectedClients(key);
```

the `AppNetowrkLogic` is an object inside the `AppInterface` singleton and it is when the `AppInterface` is created.

I have no idea how this could happen.

EDIT:
here is the `getInstance` method:

```
private static AppInterface instance=null;
public static AppInterface getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance= new AppInterface();
    }
    return instance;        
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for AppInterface.getInstance()? I suspect a race condition there.

Comment: I guess this is why the current singleton pattern is an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Just as I suspected, in a race condition by multiple clients accessing `getInstance` a race condition can occur and more than one `AppInterface` can be created.

Either eagerly create AppInterface

```
private static AppInterface instance=new AppInterface();
public static AppInterface getInstance()
{
    return instance;        
}
```

or synchronize access to `AppInterface`

```
private static AppInterface instance=null;
public static AppInterface getInstance()
{
    synchronized(AppInterface.class) {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance= new AppInterface();
        }
    }
    return instance;        
}
```

Comment: i am not sure if this matters but when the program is launched it creates the `AppInterface` in the main function and then and only then is the `AppInterface` used. Also the problem occurs after a lot of time has passed. Again not sure if it matters

Comment: @Maro Please output the table everytime when you use it. if the result is not consistent, they might related to the `getInstance` method. @shazin your second way is not thread-safe. please use [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: @qqibrow yes i have already check and it wasnt consistent, but like i said the `AppInterface` is created in the main function and the problem occurs after a long time. Usually a problem with the `getInstance` method should occur at the beginning when 2 different threads try to initialize an object but if it is created before those threads are even created there shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: @Maro could you try `private static AppInterface instance=new AppInterface();
public static AppInterface getInstance()
{
    return instance;        
} ` and is the problem still there?

Comment: @qqibrow i actually made the singleton an enum now like the suggestion on dave's comment but the problem is very hard to reproduce because this is an actual server with real clients and the problem occurs after a long period of time